# Structure needs cleaning in raspbian while compiling opencv

Tags: raspbian, opencv

Good morning 
I just want to ask a question about an error message I got all the time is that my system Raspbian said that the structure needs cleaning everytime I started to compile opencv 
and when I clean It using another installed Linux(Ubuntu) I got a messages that I lost libraries 
So How can I clean the structure everytime raspbian boot up if It possible as a normal one do before It mount the system partition like (ubuntu for exemple)
if It's not possible I just need how to clean It manually and in a safe mode please
in the picture I was compiling opencv 3.4.1 and when It's 88% the message shows up again
[image]

Comment: Post text, not illegible images

Comment: in the picture I'm compiling opencv and the message "structure needs cleaning" shows up

Comment: Please write proper sentences if you like that someone read your question. And please take the short [Tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [Help Center](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to get an idea how things work here.